Check is user admin in group or supergroup in telegram, by using get_chat_administrators&
I need to get list of group admins and check message.from_user.id in that list
@router3.message(Command('ban'))
async def ban_command(message: Message):
    admins = await bot.get_chat_administrators(chat_id=message.chat.id)
    if message.from_user.id in admins:
        await bot.ban_chat_member(user_id=message.reply_to_message.from_user.id)
    else:
        await message.answer("нет прав")

it's does not work, and all time i have else answer
what's methods can i use to do it?
